# Increase the value of several variables by one

Tags: javascript, increment

Couldn't find the solution, using wrong search terms for sure.
I want to increase the value of several variables.

++swd, ++sdd, ++smm, ++syyyy;  //s is for start week day, etc.
++(swd, sdd, smm, syyyy) //tried this, don't work

I am beginner and working on a calendar. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need that in the first place? What's wrong with doing it one after another?

Comment: For standalone variables, it's not possible without `eval` or something similarly gross. It *would* be possible if you had an object instead of multiple standalone variables.

Comment: *"I am beginner and working on a calendar."* What calendar operation does incrementing all four of those variables perform? It seems like you wouldn't be incrementing them all like that anyway...

Comment: @miomate  T.J.Crowder is right. I think you should utilize the JS Date functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The `++` operator's operand must be something writable — a variable, an object property, etc. The result of `(swd, sdd, smm, syyyy)` is not writable (and if it were, it wouldn't be the thing you want to apply `++` to).¹

Simply do what you're doing (though I wouldn't use `,` to separate those, I'd use `;`).

If those were properties of an object...

```
let obj = {
    swd: 0,
    sdd: 1,
    smm: 2,
    syyyy: 3
};
```

...you could loop through the object's properties like this:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(obj)) {
    ++obj[key];
}
```

...or in ES5

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    ++obj[key];
});
```

...but it's much more overhead and might be harder to read.

---

¹ `(swd, sdd, smm, syyyy)` is evaluated like this:

- Evaluate `swd`, then throw away the result
- Evaluate `sdd`, then throw away the result
- Evaluate `smm`, then throw away the result
- Evaluate `syyyy`, then take that result as the result of the overall `()` expression

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in ES6 using the `arguments` variable and using [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

See my example below:

```js
// Perform "callback" on all "args" and return
function performOnAll(callback, ...args) {
  for (const key in args) {
    if (args.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      args[key] = callback(args[key]);
    }
  }
  return args;
}
// TEST
// Initial values
var swd = 10,
  sdd = 11,
  smm = 12,
  syyyy = 13;
//Perform assignment
[swd, sdd, smm, syyyy] = performOnAll(function action(a) {
  return a + 10;
}, swd, sdd, smm, syyyy);
// Output result
console.log(swd, sdd, smm, syyyy);
```